# Transparent Background for Animation

Tags: transparency

How I can have an object in the foreground with a transparent background? I do not want to have a background that is just keyed out because that always leaves halos even when I do the correct lighting. So how would I go about having a background that is transparent alpha channel and all? Also what video file do I have to use to preserve the alpha channel?

Comment: How would I preserve the transparency when I animate the png?

Comment: This is not actually a duplicate question. The question that others have cited as being duplicated is about transparent PNG "files". This question is about creating transparent VIDEO files. It just so happens that for Blender Internal rendering of a QuickTime .mov file, using PNG, Animation, or AVI codecs results in videos that have an alpha channel IF the RGBA is selected and the Alpha Shading option is set to "Transparent". I routinely us this technique to generate transparent animations that I can composite in Final Cut Pro.

Comment: @neoscribe Lossy video for alpha compositing is not the greatest idea. Compression and non-linear encodings will produce an awful result. Image sequences using linearly encoded formats is the most adequate way to produce files for compositing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to go to the "Properties" panel, "Render" tab, subsection "Film" and check "Transparent".

[image: Transparency check box]

Also, keep in mind that animations should first be rendered to individual images, to avoid file corruption, and joined using something like Blender's Video Sequence Editor.
This is demonstrated [in this video](http://vimeo.com/26366908).