# exporting video with transparent background

Tags: transparency

I have searched but not found an answer that exactly answers or works.

I have a rotating rendered head animation that I want to export with a transparent background so I can import into final cut pro x and lay over video footage or still imagery. I have tried saving as a blender render as quicktime .mov with alpha as transparent and as RGBA but doesnt work, a black BG. I have also tried as a cycles render but still black BG. Is there any particular file format that is better for this? H.264, MPEG, .mov? or something I am missing? thanks

Comment: this has been asked countless of times! http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14546/transparent-background-for-animation

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/any-video-formats-that-render-with-alpha-channel. Older thread from SO - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644684/turn-image-sequence-into-video-with-transparency

Comment: That was the 1st post I went to, followed what it said and its not working.

Comment: Had to export as series of transparent pngs, then import them iinto final cut pro as images and merge together. Odd that so difficult for Blender to export a video with transparent BG?

Comment: Not all video formats support Alpha channels. Compressing to a video codec for further compositing is not the best way to do what you want. For the best quality exportas an image sequence to EXR files, else try PNG or Tiff... (or do the compositing within the blender compositor)

Answer (score 2):

Alpha and codecs don't behave terribly well. At last check, only the horrific QuickTime encoder on OSX permitted an alpha channel.

As with all good work practices, it is much more prudent to encode to a still format where plausible, and deal with encoding at the very tail end of a pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem for me.
The only solution now found, a series of PNG export, import this series in Compressor and export compatible format for Final Cut Pro.
3 manipulations instead of one.

Comment: ok, thanks.  Is there another software besides apple final cut pro that can do the Job? This is only for apple Mac and I dont't have an apple Mac.